# How To Select Distinct in MySQL or PHP, Only For Consecutive Values

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have data in a column in MySQL:

```
1   a
2   a
3   a
4   b
5   b
6   c
7   d
8   b
9   b
10  b
11  a
```

The 1st column is the `id`.
If I selected distinct the 2nd column, I'd have

```
a
b
c
d
```

However, I still need the values if they are not appearing consecutively or together, i.e. i need:

```
a
b
c
d
b
a
```

I need the 2nd "b" and 2nd "a", because rows 8,9,10 are not "together" or appearing consecutively with rows 4,5.

How can I do this with MySQL or PHP with MySQL, or even with PHP only (reading from a csv file)?

NOTE: I am using MySQL 5.6 and PHP 7

Comment: I think this is a gaps and islands problem.  This would be hard to solve using MySQL 5.6.

Comment: This is a very simple PHP problem.  Read the file sequentially, and use a variable to store the last value read, and compare it to the current one.  If the current one does not match the last one read, you write out the value and replace the last_value_read.  Requires one while loop to read each line of the csv, with an if-then clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is reasonably straightforward in MySQL alone, you just need to keep track of what the last value of 'val' was and see if the current value is different. Note that to ensure the expected result, the values from table1 need to be ordered by id before being processed. Otherwise, dependent on the order of inserts you might get unexpected results...

```
SELECT id, @last := val AS value
FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id) t
JOIN (SELECT @last := '') l
WHERE val != @last
```

Output

```
id  value
1   a
4   b
6   c
7   d
8   b
11  a
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d6fbc/4)

Comment: This is awesome, btw can you tell me what do we call this operator _(@last)_ are there more like these ?

Comment: @Viney `@last` is a variable. In the `JOIN` table I am setting it to an empty string (`''`) and then on each pass through the values table I am setting it equal to the last value seen (`@last := val`).  See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) for more info on how to use variables

Comment: You're missing an ORDER BY clause

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, I hadn't considered data insertion order. Query corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP only:

```
$data = [
    1 => 'a',
    2 => 'a',
    3 => 'a',
    4 => 'b',
    5 => 'b',
    6 => 'c',
    7 => 'd',
    8 => 'b',
    9 => 'b',
    10 => 'b',
    11 => 'a',
];

$result = [];
foreach ($data as $value) {
    if (count($result) === 0)
        $result[] = $value;
    elseif (end($result) !== $value)
        $result[] = $value;
}
```